# Are Yasuo's Q stacks lost after revival?

Tags: league-of-legends

Example: Yasuo hits twice with Q so he gets his airborne strike ready, then he dies and resurrects either by Guardian Angel's passive or Zilean's ult.

Will Yasuo's stacks disappear after resurrection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of the game code, the death counter increments if and only if a death occurs. In other words, *you do not count as having died if you are immediately revived*.

You lose buffs if you die. If you do not die, you do not lose buffs. Yasuo's Q stacks are counted as buffs. Thus, **Guardian Angel and Chronoshift will preserve Yasuo's Q stacks.**